# Application Error on Sinatra app deployed on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, cloud9

I have built an app in a course I was taking in Cloud 9 using the Sinatra framework and deployed it using Heroku. However when I launch the app I get an application error. I have the following files;

**config.ru**

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

set :app_file, __FILE__
run Sinatra::Application
```

**environment.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'active_support/all'

# Load Sinatra Framework (with AR)
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/contrib/all' # Requires cookies, among other things

require 'pry'

APP_ROOT = Pathname.new(File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__))
APP_NAME = APP_ROOT.basename.to_s

# Sinatra configuration
configure do
  set :root, APP_ROOT.to_path
  set :server, :puma

  enable :sessions
  set :session_secret, ENV['SESSION_KEY'] || 'lighthouselabssecret'

  set :views, File.join(Sinatra::Application.root, "app", "views")
end

# Set up the database and models
require APP_ROOT.join('config', 'database')

# Load the routes / actions
require APP_ROOT.join('app', 'actions')
```

**EDITS**

**Heroku Logs**

```
2017-06-06T13:44:57.586652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby environment.rb -p 35256`
2017-06-06T13:45:00.219635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-06-06T13:45:00.138353+00:00 app[web.1]: ruby: No such file or directory -- environment.rb (LoadError)
2017-06-06T13:45:00.221194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-06T15:14:43.483731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-06-06T15:14:46.326391+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby environment.rb -p 43667`
2017-06-06T15:14:49.114108+00:00 app[web.1]: ruby: No such file or directory -- environment.rb (LoadError)
2017-06-06T15:14:49.213798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-06T15:14:49.200516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-06-06T15:44:11.537127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stormy-atoll-29193.herokuapp.com request_id=1eecc885-da1a-4333-8254-7f05febc23db fwd="170.146.14.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-06T15:44:11.767259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stormy-atoll-29193.herokuapp.com request_id=eb39d22e-fe01-4abd-8ccf-1a5d17635b7d fwd="170.146.14.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a `web.rb` file, as described in the heroku docs (see here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby-o)?

Comment: @Puhlze No, my understanding is that I am using the config.rb to call environment.rb rather than web.rb, not sure where the logs are picking up web.rb from

Comment: @Puhlze I think web.rb must just be the default file that's loaded when there's no Procfile. In the link you provided there's info about that. Also, I think it's supposed to config.ru not config.rb

Comment: The log line:

     <time> heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby web.rb -p 53260`

suggests Heroku is starting the process with web.rb as the entry. Do you have a Procfile committed in your repository?

Comment: @Kashyap I do have a procflie with `web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT` as the only line of code in it. I changed the web.rb to environment.rb but I am still getting errors. 

Also thanks max it is config.ru, my mistake

Comment: The error this time would be different. In the Procfile, if you're using `config.ru`, the command that can be used is: `web: bundle exec rackup -p $PORT`